# ReactJs find the appropriate value in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this javascript object that represents a trello board: 
[image: board object]

I have an onCardClick function that contains cardId, metadata, and laneId.

I thought of converting the the hole object to array with **Object.values** and then looping through that array but it still has objects inside of it, so I think using .map/forEach function won't do the trick to retrieve a single card.
any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Post the object as code and expected result, then it's easy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to retrieve a single trello card object inside this nested object ?

```
for (const lane of object.lanes) {
  for (const card of lane.cards) {
    if (card.id === cardID) {
      // This is the card you are looking for
      doSomethingWith(card);
    }
  }
}
```

This can be done with `Array.forEach` as well (`Array.map` would also work but it's unecessary to return the whole array so you shouldn't use it for this case)